# PyCharm can't resolve stackless

Tags: python, pycharm, built-in, python-stackless

I am using PyCharm 3 on OS X. I've configured a Python Stackless binary in virtual env to be used as a project interpreter. It runs okay, and imports `stackless` module, but in the editor it is showed with a red underline and PyCharm says it cannot resolve the import.

How can it be fixed? Should I do something with builtins config?

Comment: I have the same issue and look like no one cares .... what is your current IDE/intelisense solution for stackless?

Comment: @John Sorry to dissapoint you, actually I've dumped the idea of using stackless python. So I've never solved the issue with IDE

Comment: i see, so what else did you use for better concurrency?

Comment: Well, I've just used default threading module – it was enough in my situation